# JQuery Post URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Jquery function

```
function refreshTheGrid(myData, ceduleDateFrom, ceduleDateTo, paramOrderNo) {



    var myData2 = {
        CeduleDateFrom: ceduleDateFrom,
        CeduleDateTo: ceduleDateTo,
        ParamOrderNo: paramOrderNo
    };


    var theUrl = "UpdateCheckBox";
    var theUrl2 = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        data: myData,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: theUrl2,
                data: myData2,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#monbouton').click();
                }
            })
        }
    })
   popup.Hide();
    void (0);
}
```

My Application is `http://localhost/JprMvc/`

when my POST Method are called the following is capture by Fiddler2

```
POST /JprMvc/CeduleGlobale/UpdateCheckBox HTTP/1.1
```

and

```
POST /JprMvc/ HTTP/1.1
```

I had a problem with the call until I removed the CeduleGlobale part from my URL.  Now everything works.

I think it's a routing problem, but I am not sure.

my routing is

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "CeduleGlobale", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

It works now, but it seems arbitrary.

Should I remove the defaults from my routing and put it back in the jquery.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally leave the routing as a default and change the controller in the jQuery call.

Routing Code

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

jQuery Code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 300000, //5 minutes (in milliseconds)
        url: '/YourApplicationName/YourContollerName/YourMethodName',

//...
```

Comment: the myData is the parameter passed in the function call, mydata2 is a simpler data passed as a parameter in the second function call, this is by design.

Comment: The problem is that my Application doesn't have a home controller.  the home is CeduleGlobale.  Is that a big no no ?

Comment: I do not think it is a no no, to me it seems better practice.  I only added the second part because I thought I had spotted your issue.  I do not see anything you are doing incorrect.